# Constructing a Ruby Binary Tree from String

Tags: ruby, algorithm, binary-tree

A bit of a newbie to computing science.

I have the basics for a binary tree in Ruby:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :left, :right, :value
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
end
```

This works fine if I construct it manually, for example, if I want `tom` to be a child node of `ben`:

```
ben = Node.new('Ben')
tom = Node.new('Tom')

ben.left = tom
```

One of the challenges I need to figure out is how to construct a tree for inputted parent/child pairs. Here is an example input string:

```
peter tom
peter marie
marie john
tom oscar
```

My binary tree would look something like this:

```
    peter
      |
 tom     marie
  |        |
oscar     john
```

I am wondering if I can get some direction into converting multiple strings in the following format `"[parent] [child]"` into a binary tree.

Thanks :)

Comment: With a `[parent] [child]` format, how do you decide whether a child goes into `left` or `right`? Likewise, what happens if the input contains more than two child entries for a given parent?

Comment: Values can be unique ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hash to store the data:

```
data = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Node.new k }

while !(line = gets.strip).empty?
    parent, child = line.split.map { |value| data[value] }
    if !parent.left
        parent.left = child
    elsif !parent.right
        parent.right = child
    else
        raise "#{parent.value} already has both a left and right child"
    end
end
```

Comment: Nice solution, especially the way you've defined `data`. One small thing: you need something like `while (line = gets.strip) != '`'. As it is you'll never break out of the loop.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Fixed.

Comment: Awesome solution! Worked perfectly. Thanks